# Function acting as both decorator and context manager in Python?

Tags: python, decorator, contextmanager

This might be pushing things a little too far, but mostly out of curiosity..

Would it be possible to have a callable object (function/class) that acts as *both* a Context Manager and a decorator at the same time:

```
def xxx(*args, **kw):
    # or as a class

@xxx(foo, bar)
def im_decorated(a, b):
    print('do the stuff')

with xxx(foo, bar):
    print('do the stuff')
```

Comment: can you give an example of what it would do? are the two functionalities different?

Comment: It would basically being two alternate ways of setting up fixtures in test suites.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Starting in Python 3.2, support for this is even included in the standard library.  Deriving from the class [`contextlib.ContextDecorator`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) makes it easy to write classes that can be used as both, a decorator or a context manager.  This functionality could be easily backported to Python 2.x -- here is a basic implementation:

```
class ContextDecorator(object):
    def __call__(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwds):
            with self:
                return f(*args, **kwds)
        return decorated
```

Derive your context manager from this class and define the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods as usual.

Comment: You can use contextlib2 if you must use Python2: http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: This might help:https://coderwall.com/p/0lk6jg/python-decorators-vs-context-managers-have-your-cake-and-eat-it

Comment: Using python 3.8.5, adding or removing the line `@functools.wraps(f)` does not change anything and both context manager and argument-less decorator work. Why is that?

Comment: @Guimoute Please read the documentation of `functools.wraps()` to understand what it does. It doesn't change the way the wrapper function _works_, but it changes the way it _looks_ when inspecting it. For example the wrapper inherits the docstring and the name of the wrapped function.

Answer (score 59):

In Python 3.2+, you can define a context manager that is also a decorator using [`@contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

From the docs:

> [`contextmanager()`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) uses [`ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) so the context managers it creates can be used as decorators as well as in [`with`](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statements

Example usage:

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager
>>> @contextmanager
... def example_manager(message):
...     print('Starting', message)
...     try:
...         yield
...     finally:
...         print('Done', message)
... 
>>> with example_manager('printing Hello World'):
...     print('Hello, World!')
... 
Starting printing Hello World
Hello, World!
Done printing Hello World
>>> 
>>> @example_manager('running my function')
... def some_function():
...     print('Inside my function')
... 
>>> some_function()
Starting running my function
Inside my function
Done running my function
```

Comment: If `example_manager` yielded a result, how would we get access to that when used as a decorator?

Comment: @coler-j You can't from https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html >Note that there is one additional limitation when using context managers as function decorators: there’s no way to access the return value of __enter__(). If that value is needed, then it is still necessary to use an explicit with statement.

Answer (score 17):

```
class Decontext(object):
    """
    makes a context manager also act as decorator
    """
    def __init__(self, context_manager):
        self._cm = context_manager
    def __enter__(self):
        return self._cm.__enter__()
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self._cm.__exit__(*args, **kwds)
    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
            with self:
                return func(*args, **kwds)
        return wrapper
```

now you can do:

```
mydeco = Decontext(some_context_manager)
```

and that allows both

```
@mydeco
def foo(...):
    do_bar()

foo(...)
```

and

```
with mydeco:
    do_bar()
```

Comment: How would you pass arguments to the decorator if the context manager takes arguments ?

Comment: @Warz context manager already being created during `Decontext(some_context_manager)`. `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are pre-defined.

Comment: Related question using `Decontext` with arguments: [Passing arguments to decontext decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190979/passing-arguments-to-decontext-decorator)

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example:

```
class ContextDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        print("init", foo, bar)

    def __call__(self, f):
        print("call")
        def wrapped_f():
            print("about to call")
            f()
            print("done calling")
        return wrapped_f

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("exit")

with ContextDecorator(1, 2):
    print("with")

@ContextDecorator(3, 4)
def sample():
    print("sample")

sample()
```

This prints:

```
init 1 2
enter
with
exit
init 3 4
call
about to call
sample
done calling
```

Comment: When used as a decorator, this won't act in the same way as a context manager, which seems to be the OP's intention. (See the OP's comment -- "It would basically being two alternate ways of setting up fixtures in test suites.")

Comment: Sure, the point was to show how to have a single class do both. I would leave it up to the OP to customize it for intended functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Although I agree (and upvoted) @jterrace here, I'm adding a very slight variation that returns the decorated function, and includes arguments for both the decorator and the decorated function.

```
class Decon:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, c=True):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __enter__(self):
        # only need to return self 
        # if you want access to it
        # inside the context
        return self 

    def __exit__(self, exit_type, exit_value, exit_traceback):
        # clean up anything you need to
        # otherwise, nothing much more here
        pass

    def __call__(self, func):
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorator
```

Comment: Looks nice! When the world starts to be properly updated to 3.6+ I'll stick to https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator but while 2- is a risk your solution looks very tempting!

Comment: Worked lika a charm.

Comment: This solution allows one to use the arguments of the wrapped function or method, which none of the other solutions allows.